# scrollview vs listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview

I have to display a list of 100 images with text, can someonce please tell me whether can I use the ScrollView or listview to improve the performance.

thanks,
venu

Comment: ScrollView is the normal behavior of scrolling the content. A ListView dynamically finds the content and loads it with an adapter, this is useful if you have lots of content that would fill up all the memory.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a listview because not all items load at once... but it's slower when you scroll...

Answer (score 3):

As long as you create an efficient list view adapter, you should have no problems with the list view. Take a look at the API demos which have a very efficient list adapter and also Romain Guy's 2009 google IO talk on list views - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 0):

i used listview in my RssFeed Reader but it was not efficiently